# Postgresql 11.1: "Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. Error with configuration or permissions."

Tags: postgresql

I checked the log file and I think this is the part that caused the problem:

```
Setting up database 
[15:30:54] Configuring pg11 to point to existing data dir D:\John's Files\My Documents\Code\Databases\PostgreSQL\data\pg11 
Setting PostgreSQL port
= 5432 
Executing C:\Installed Software\Developer Software\PostgreSQLv11.1/pgc config pg11 --datadir "D:\John's Files\My Documents\Code\Databases\PostgreSQL\data\pg11" 
Script exit code: 1

Script output:  ################################################
# FATAL SQL Error in check_release
#    SQL Message =  near "s": syntax error
#  SQL Statement = SELECT r.component FROM releases r, versions v   
 WHERE r.component = v.component     
    AND r.component LIKE '%D:\John's Files\My Documents\Code\Databases\PostgreSQL\data\pg11%' AND v.is_current = 1
################################################

Script stderr:  Program ended with an error exit code

Error with configuration or permissions. Please see log file for more information. 
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly      
Error with configuration or permissions. Please see log file for more information.
```

I think the problem is the apostrophe in "John's". Does anyone know if that's right? Is there a fix to this problem? I don't want to rename my directory because Postgresql can't handle apostrophes.

Comment: Try to install it in a folder without any special char eg `John' <--- s`

Comment: And yes. You will probably have to rename your folder or find a workaround to escape that.

Comment: Jorge, thanks for confirming that.

Comment: That's a bug in OpenSCG's bi aries. You should report it to them.